# Couldn't run loadjava on user schema to load dbwsclientws.jar dbwsclientdb102.jar

Tags: schema, loadjava

I am trying to load oracle webservice client jars to my schema. I did set the PATH to inlcude:
/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/bin
When I try to run loadjava as "loadjava -u myschema/myscehmapwd -r -v -f -genmissing dbwsclientws.jar dbwsclientdb102.jar"
I am getting error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/aurora/server/tools/loadjava/LoadJavaMain. Does it mean that jvm is not setup on the box? How can I check if the jvm is enabled or not?

I am running it on Oracle 10g in UNIX environment.

Any help with the issue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `classpath` in the documentation to ensure that you have all of the files mentioned in the `classpath`, such as `$ORACLE_HOME/javavm/lib/aurora.zip`